# How do you create new windows workspace with TFS command line client that is running on unix

Tags: unix, tfs, command-line-tool, team-explorer-everywhere

How would I work with the TFS command line client that is running on a aix/unix box to run the tf commands. For example I'm unable to create local windows workspaces that connect to the tfs version control folders that are on a windows server. The version of command line client that is running on the unix box is (/TFS/TEE-CLC-12.0.0). I can't find any documentation how the client can be used when running on unix to connect local windows files to the version control files on a server.

Comment: What have you tried?  Have you followed the tutorial at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc31bk2e.aspx ?

Comment: Thanks for the link Edward. I am using the command line client which is independent from visual studio. My code is cobol so the programmers here don't use visual studio. I am testing out this client to possible change how we maintain our code repository. 1. The plugin is loaded, configued and working on the unix server. 2. I can create workspaces on our tfs windows server (our code repository resides there). However I can't figure out how to create a local workspace on my computer and map/connect/checkin my code changes to the tfs repository via the plugin loaded on the unix box.

Comment: Indeed, the commands for the cross-platform command-line client (part of Team Explorer Everywhere) are the same as the command-line client bundled with Visual Studio.  You need to use the `tf workspace /new` command to create a workspace.  There should be examples in the link I provided.

Comment: Those are not examples that are running from a unix server. They are running in the command prompt from a windows computer.

Comment: Yes, that's correct.  But since - as I mentioned - the commands are the same on Unix and on Windows, that shouldn't matter.  If you're running into a problem while running the commands, could you post additional details of the problem you're running into?

Comment: For example this is the suggested command to create a new workspace: tf workspace -new Beta1 -collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection. Would I substitute that collection url for a local folder (e.g., C:\tfsprojects\test) in order to create a local workspace? From the explanations I've seen the collection is the version control folder and you need to be sourced to your local folder when you create a new workspace (e.g., c:\tfsprojects\test>tf workspace -new -collection:http://myserver:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection), but this particular command would not work from a unix server.

Comment: No, you do not change the server URL or specify any Windows paths.  You just need to specify the server path and a local path on your Unix box.  I wrote an answer that walks you through getting the source code locally.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Getting source files down from the server requires three steps on any platform:

1. Create a **workspace** on your server.  A workspace is what contains the metadata about the files you want on the server and the files you have locally.

   (Technically, you don't create a workspace on the *server*, you do it on a *Team Project Collection* which is a logical unit in the server; by default you have a single Team Project Collection on your server called - uncreatively - "DefaultCollection".)
2. Create one or more **working folder mappings** that indicate the server's file paths you want to get, and where to put them on your local disk.  For an uncomplicated project, this is as simple as mapping `$/Project/Folder` to `C:\Project\Folder` or `/project/folder`.
3. Do a **get**, to download the files from the server, placing them in the local folders you configured in step 2.

For example, I have a cross-platform project which happens to be Team Explorer Everywhere itself.  In this case my server is `https://tee.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection`.  My source is located on the server at `$/TEE/Main`.  And I want to place it on my AIX box is `/build/tee/main`.

Neither the server nor the server folder change because I'm not on Windows.  The only thing that changes is - unsurprisingly - the local path.  I'll walk through these steps on my AIX 5.2 box:

1. Create a workspace:

   ```
   ethomson@aix:~% tf workspace -new MyWorkspace -collection:https://tee.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection
   Workspace 'MyWorkspace' created.
   ```
2. Create a working folder mapping from `$/TEE/Main` to `/build/tee/main`:

   ```
   ethomson@aix:~% tf workfold -map '$/TEE/Main' /build/tee/main -collection:https://tee.visualstudio.com/DefaultCollection -workspace:MyWorkspace
   ```
3. Get the files.  (Now that you have configured a working folder mapping, you do not need to specify the server URL or the workspace name as long as you specify the local path.)

   ```
   ethomson@aix:~% cd /build/tee/main
   ethomson@aix:/build/tee/main% tf get -recursive .
   /build/tee:
   Getting main

   /build/tee/main:
   Getting build

   /build/tee/main/build:
   Getting .project
   Getting .settings
   ...etc...
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the in-depth explanation and answer Edward. How would your example work if your code was located on your local computer at /build/tee/main? If you ran the command cd /build/tee/main from your aix box that would throw an error of /build/tee/main not found, because that path is on your local computer and not on the unix box. Does my question make sense? I'm dealing with 3 moving parts developing on local computer, running the command line client from a unix server, and working with version control code on a separate window server.

Comment: No, I don't understand.  My local computer *is* the unix box...?

Comment: That's been the issue. Our programming setup is a bit different. We have cobol code that runs on aix boxes and our code repository resides on a windows server, both of which we log into from our local windows machines.

Comment: Okay, well.  I don't understand what you *want* TFS to do here.  It sounds like you need to *deploy* to the AIX box?  Team Explorer Everywhere will only help your Unix box talk to the TFS server.  It doesn't - indeed, can't - know about this windows server you have with some code on it.  You need to either check it in so that you can do a get on the AIX box or figure out another deployment mechanism (scp?  rsync?).  Unless I still misunderstand your setup?

Comment: Thanks for your help Edward. Your example makes sense now. Is the command line client deployed on the aix box? Mine is deployed from the aix box at /opt/TFS/TEE-CLC-12.0.0. Is this typically?

Comment: @jjohnston Awesome!  Yes, that's almost exactly where I have mine installed.