# Connect VS code with TFS on mac

Tags: macos, tfs, visual-studio-code

How to connect **Visual Studio Code** on **mac** with **Team Foundation Server**(TFS).

Or any other way to connect with tfs?

Comment: For Git or for TFVC?

Comment: @DanielMann for both

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This are the steps to effectively connect a TFS (TFVC) Repository to your VS Code on Mac:

**INSTALL THE SOFTWARE**

1. Install Visual Studio Code for Mac (currently here: https://code.visualstudio.com/download).
2. Install the TFS extension for VS Code: Go to the Extensions tab in VS Code, Search for TFS and install.
3. Install TEE-CLC. Follow this guide: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNaEIVZfr0&feature=youtu.be.

**CREATE A LOCAL TFVC WORKSPACE IN YOUR MAC**

Now you need to have a local TFVC Workspace on your machine. If you don't have one (as it was my case), you need to create it. The following steps are partially extracted from https://stackoverflow.com/a/21785438/2816119.

1. Create a local folder where you are going to download and locally store the source code.
2. Open a Terminal window.
3. Create a local workspace from your terminal window with the following command:

   ```
   tf workspace -new MyWorkspace -collection:<<<http://full.URL.of/your/repository>>>
   ```
4. Map your repository folder to your local folder with the following command:

   ```
   tf workfold -map '$/your/repository/folder/path' /your/local/folder/path -collection:<<<http://full.URL.of/your/repository>>> -workspace:MyWorkspace
   ```
5. If everything went well, you'll see a new sub-folder "**.tf**" in your local folder.
6. Open your local folder with VS Code. If everything went well you'll se after a few seconds the TFVC icons in the bottom bar:
   [image]

**GET THE SOURCE CODE**

To get the source code you'll need to go to the **Source Control Tab** -> **Ellipsis (...) button** -> **Sync**.

[image]

Once you press it you'll see a progress bar moving in the Source Control Tab and you'll see how the source code is downloaded to your local folder.

**ENJOY**

Now you can use your TFVC repository as described in their guides.
If something is not clear or you have questions please let me know. I'll try to help you :-)

Comment: TEE-CLC can be downloaded from here: https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases

Comment: I finally got it to work but I still don't have a ".tf" folder. The VSCode extension finds what it needs by running `tf workfold /your/local/folder/path`

Comment: @PatrickMcElhaney please note the .tf folder is hidden by default. Press "CMD + SHIFT + ." on Finder to reveal hidden folders. Please let me know if that was the case.

Comment: @juangalf It's really not there. Did not show in in Bash with `ls -a`. I've since found that it works even if I create the mapping before creating the folder.

Comment: Can we send/Receive & perform Code reviews/request from here?

Comment: @GreenRobo I'm not sure as I've never used that functionality. Maybe it's available using a command for the Team Services extension? Maybe this resources can help you: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sk6LrzQX4P8&feature=youtu.be or https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode . Please let us know what you find. Thank you.

Comment: @juangalf Thank you for your reply. I tried given github url but no luck. you can find same information mentioned here. https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/292

Comment: I also was not able to get a `.tf` folder, despite everything suceeding. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: @mcsilvio Please make sure you are able to view invisible files in your system. One quick way to do this is to create the .tf folder manually and check if you can view the folder with a new Finder window.

Comment: `ls -la` is what I used.

Comment: A vital detail, the extension seems to be only available for version 2017 of Visual Studio release 7.5 or later. I ended up manually downloading version 7.8.4.1 of Visual Studio Professional for Mac OSX and was then finally able to see and install the TFS extension.

Answer (score 6):

### Get the software

- [tee-clc](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere) (can be installed with [HomeBrew](https://brewinstall.org/install-tee-clc-on-mac-with-brew/)), *which depends on*
- Java 6, 7, or 8 (see [How to install Java 8 on Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24342886/how-to-install-java-8-on-mac) -- as of this writing, [Java 9 will not work](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/237).)

### Create a workspace using tee-clc ("tf")

Tell tee-clc to remember your credentials (in OSX's Keychain) by adding this line to your `.bash_profile`. Then close and reopen your terminal or just paste the same command.

```
export TF_AUTO_SAVE_CREDENTIALS=0
```

Accept the EULA.

```
tf eula
```

Create a workspace.

```
tf workspace -new MyCoolWorkspace -collection:https://my-server.example.com/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

Map a path on the server to a local folder.

```
tf workfold -map '$/Path/To/Folder' /path/to/your/local/folder -collection:https://your-server.example.com/tfs/DefaultCollection  -workspace:MyCoolWorkspace
```

Get the code and store your password. Make sure you type your actual username; if you enter `your_username` here it may get stored in the OSX Keychain and tee-clc is really dumb about replacing it later.

```
cd /path/to/your/local/folder
tf get -login:your_username
```

If it works, it will download your code to that folder. You can also use the [other commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873092(v=vs.120).aspx).

### Use the Azure Repos Extension on VS Code

Get the [Azure Repos](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode) extension.

Add the following settings (CMD+,):

```json
{
    "tfvc.location": "/usr/local/bin/tf",
    "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true
}
```

Type `which tf` in Terminal to find out what the value for location should be. I'm not sure if "restrictWorkspace" is necessary. I got it from a [comment on Github](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/issues/352#issuecomment-361880196) while I was troubleshooting.

Finally, open the folder containing your code. From the command palette (⌘+⇧+P) type `Team: Signin`. If that works, you can start using the other features in the plugin.

Comment: I can get right up to the last step..but no luck.  TEE-CLC is working and "tf workfold" from a VSCode 1.19 Terminal produces the expected workspace.  But though many "Team:" commands are listed on the command palette, running any of them such as "Team: Signin" produces "command 'team.Signin' not found".  Any ideas?

Comment: Check and make sure your password is stored correctly in the Keychain. Also look for clues in team-extension.log which should be created in your local folder.

Comment: I confirmed the keychain which had my "[user].visualstudio.com" name, Kind=Internet Password, and date-stamped properly.  I also confirmed the .bash_profile edits.  Once confirming both....it just started working...  Thanks for the help and prompt reply.

Comment: This worked for me as far as getting `tf` installed and the codebase downloaded. In my case including the `/DefaultCollection` at the end seemed to cause errors and I had to remove it.

Comment: I have the next error: **No Azure DevOps Services or Team Foundation Server repository configuration was found. Ensure you've opened a folder that contains a repository**. I am tired nothings work.

Answer (score 1):

### GIT

VS Code ships with a Git source control manager (SCM) extension. Most of the source control UI and work flows are common across  SCM extensions.

More details please refer this tutorial：[Using Version Control in VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol)

***Note:*** *VS Code will leverage your machine's Git installation, so you need to install Git first before you get these features. Make sure you install at least version 2.0.0.*

---

### TFVC

You can connect to TFVC using the [Visual Studio Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) since version 1.116.0 (2017/04/12).

***Note:*** *You need Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 or later.*

Comment: I have tried with this, but its connecting to the vusualstudio.com server, I need to connect my local TFS server

Comment: Hi @Ganesh This could also connect to local TFS , which version control are you using tfvc or Git ,besides which version of TFS are you working on?

Comment: Thank you, Currently No version control, I have a Tfs account and just downloaded the Visual studio code and installed the team services extension

Now I have a project folder with created in Visual studio 2017, need to manage with my Tfs account in server.

So can you please let me know how to do this process.

Thank you,

Comment: Do you know How to get the TFVC path location in Mac?

Comment: @Ganesh sorry for the later reply, you just need to  have a local TFVC workspace available. As a new user,  you can find that information (**including demo videos**) in our [TFVC documentation](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md)--**Getting Started Videos**.

Comment: @Patrick-MSFT you can't do that. In the documentation and in the video I see: "Open a folder containing a Local TFVC Workspace and sign in when prompted".

As a new user, you don't have a local TFVC workspace. How can someone check this out? All the docs are very unclear.

I did this myself by using Visual Studio 2017 on Windows, where you can install Visual Studio Enterprise. On Mac, all the installation files points to the same Visual Studio Community version which _cannot_ connect to TFVC. 

So, it's impossible for a Mac user to get the first checkout of a TFVC repo. What now?

Comment: @Richh94 you're right, the documentation is very unclear, but I finally managed to create a brand new TFVC repository in Mac using only TEE-CLC. You can check my answer below: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006473/2816119.

Answer (score -1):

Check the below link. It is working fine for me

[How to use TFS on a Mac](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/01/28/how-to-use-tfs-on-a-mac.aspx)

Steps to be followed:

**Step 1:** Install Eclipse

**Step 2:** Download and install the TFS everywhere plugin

**Step 3:** Checkout your solution using the eclipse to a local folder

**Step 4:** Open the solution in Visual studio and make the code changes

**Step 5:** Open eclipse and commit your changes.

Comment: That seems like the worst solution. Using Eclipse IDE to do checkin/out, and using VSCode IDE to do edits.

Comment: Visual studio for MAC IDE doesn't have TFS integration yet from Microsoft. That's why I am suggesting an alternate way. check the link https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/56252/why-not-include-tfs-in-vs-for-mac.html

Comment: I am not saying your answer is wrong. I am just saying that @Patrick-MSFT, and MS should come up with a better solution.

Comment: After spending hours on this. This appears to be the only solution that works today. It must be an older version of Eclipse too. I used Neon.