# How to configure local existing TFS server in Visual Studio 2017 Mac?

Tags: macos, tfs, visual-studio-2017

I am working on Xamarin with Visual Studio 2017. My organization has its own domain base TFS server, Now I need to configure that server to my Visual Studio 2017 Mac version projects.

I found the Visual Studio code is capable to connect the TFS, but it's connecting the Visualstudio.com server, I need to connect to the server which is my organization.

Comment: Hi Ganesh. Please reply to @Patrick, who has taken the time to give you assistance. Did you find the answer below of any use? If so, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it. Let me know when you have read this, so I can remove my downvote, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

For visual studio Mac, TFS isn't supported for now. There has been a uservocie, you can vote up and monitor it.

> **TFS Version Control**
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17136163-tfs-version-control

---

However as a workaround, you could use Visual Studio Code to connect on-premise
TFS server.

### TFVC

You can connect to TFVC using the [Visual Studio Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) since version 1.116.0 (2017/04/12). This extension allows you to connect to Team Services and Team Foundation Server.

***Note:*** *You need Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 or later.*

More details please take a look at my reply at this question: [Connect VS code with TFS on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178141/connect-vs-code-with-tfs-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Here is an alternate way of doing the same.It is working fine for me

[How to use TFS on a Mac](https://www.infragistics.com/community/blogs/stevez/archive/2013/01/28/how-to-use-tfs-on-a-mac.aspx)

Steps to be followed:

**Step 1:** Install Eclipse

**Step 2:** Download and install the TFS everywhere plugin

**Step 3:** Checkout your solution using the eclipse to a local folder

**Step 4:** Open the solution in Visual studio and make the code changes

**Step 5:** Open eclipse and commit your changes.