# Is TFS available in Visual Studio for Mac

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-mac

I haven’t find TFS in Visual Studio  for mac, Is any alternative tools available for that.

Comment: Do you mean Team Explorer by TFS in your question?

Comment: Yes Ali, I am asking for the same

Comment: Than, the last part of Gerald Answer is what you need. The extension is there in the new update 7.5 but it's not stable as the comments. I will be trying it today and reply back to you.

Comment: Thanks Ali , I have also stuck on the same

Comment: I am not able to download any extension after the update. I am not sure if it's bug or the issue is on my side only. It looks like no one is complaining about that though

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TFS is a rather broad term and describes a whole suite of solutions. I’m assuming that you mean the version control section for my answer.

There is no support for [TFVC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/overview?view=vsts), which is the older versioning control system that used to be default in TFS.

Since some time now, TFS and VSTS (basically the cloud hosted version of TFS) have switched to Git. Git is supported from Visual Studio for Mac as well as a lot of other tools of course.

If you still want to use TFVC, I have only found one option which isn't pretty. I installed Eclipse (the IDE for Java) which has a plugin for the TFVC version control. It looks and works pretty similar to how it looks in Visual Studio for Windows. It has some quirks and I would be surprised if it is still actively maintained, so use with caution and if you have the possibility look into switching to Git.

**Edit** though they seem to be [working on it!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/07/visual-studio-for-mac-version-7-5-and-beyond/) If you check out the linked blog post you will see that support is in the works and I think there is a preview you can download today.

Comment: From the comments, It's clear that it's not stable and many people are facing issue with it. 

But why are you focusing on TFVC on your answer? Nobody has mention that they will be using it. 

Cool answer nonetheless.

Comment: Clarified this a bit. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio Mac, TFS is supported for now. There has been a uservocie, you can vote up and monitor it.

> TFS Version Control
>
> https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/563332-visual-studio-for-mac/suggestions/17136163-tfs-version-control

However, this is only a preview feature as you can see the comment from PM:

> I’m happy to say that **our first preview of this feature is now
>   available** – check out the announcement blog post.
>
> **https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/07/visual-studio-for-mac-version-7-5-and-beyond/**
>
> I’ll continue to share out updates here as we make updates to the
>   preview.
>
> *Jordan Program Manager, Visual Studio for Mac*

According to the comment below the blog post, it seems not stable for now. If you want a more stably solution of using TFS source control on Mac, you could try to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/), which is more of a fast, lightweight code editor.

With the help of [Visual Studio Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) on Visual Studio Code, it allows you to connect to Team Services and Team Foundation Server and provides support for both Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC) and GIT. More details can be found at [Connect VS code with TFS on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178141/connect-vs-code-with-tfs-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

As of VS 2019 for MAC, support for preview as well has been dropped.

> Caution
>
> The preview TFVC extension for Visual Studio for Mac is no longer supported in Visual Studio 2019 for Mac.

As per this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019), it's recommended to use GIT for version control. Otherwise, if there's no option then to use TFS on macOS several options are also provided in the link.

> - Option 1. [Use Visual Studio Code and the Azure Repos extension, for a
>     graphical UI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019#use-visual-studio-code-and-the-azure-repos-extension)
> - Option 2. [Connect to your repo using the Team Explorer Everywhere Command Line Client (TEE-CLC)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019#connecting-using-the-team-explorer-everywhere-command-line-client)

Also, there's [eclipse plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/category/free-tagging/microsoft-tfs) available for TFVC on mac