# Visual Studio team services for Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio, xamarin, azure-devops

I am working on Xamarin visual studio on Mac and we are using visual studio team services for our project.I have no problem pulling the code but I can't seem to be able to Check in any file I modify to the team service.

Comment: What‘s the detail error  when you check in files to team service locally? Which version control are you using TFVC or GIT in VSTS?

Comment: Any update on this？

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **GIT** just take a look at below tutorials:

- [Working with Git on Visual Studio Mac](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/working-with-git)
- [Xamarin DevOps with VSTS - Getting Started](http://www.blogaboutxamarin.com/xamarin-dev-ops-with-vsts-getting-started/)(*Visual Studio for Mac has replaced Xamarin Studio*, *but similar steps on git*)

For visual studio Mac, **TFVC** also supported for now. 
However, this is only a preview feature as you can see the comment from PM:

> I’m happy to say that **our first preview of this feature is now
>   available** – check out the announcement blog post.
>
> **https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudio/2018/05/07/visual-studio-for-mac-version-7-5-and-beyond/**
>
> I’ll continue to share out updates here as we make updates to the
>   preview.
>
> *Jordan Program Manager, Visual Studio for Mac*

According to the comment below the blog, seems not stable for now.

---

For now, you want a  more stably solution of using TFVC source control on Mac.  You could try to use [Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/) , which is more of a quick; light weight code editor.

With the help of [Visual Studio Team Services extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team) on Visual Studio Code, it allows you to connect to Team Services and Team Foundation Server and provides support for both Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC), GIT. More details please take a look at [Connect VS code with TFS on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178141/connect-vs-code-with-tfs-on-mac)