# Visual Studio for Mac: Connecting to TFS

Tags: macos, visual-studio, tfs, terminal

Using Mac OS 10.13.6 and Visual Studio for Mac Community v7.5.4
Trying to connect to my company's TFS and access the files. I got stuck when it would not let me create a Workspace. I found this thread:

[Connect VS code with TFS on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178141/connect-vs-code-with-tfs-on-mac)

It says to download from https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases a zip staring with TEE-CLC... which I did. In Terminal, when I try running the command at the 1:20 mark in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNaEIVZfr0&feature=youtu.be) nothing happens. I double click the tf command in my Finder window and a Terminal window opens showing "Saving session...copying shared history...saving history...[Process completed]". Again, nothing happens.

I think I'm the only person at my company who is trying to use VS for Mac. Any thoughts?? I'm at the end of my rope just about.

Comment: What error did you get when you create a workspace?

Answer (score 1):

The thread you are referring to is for `Visual Studio Code`. Since you are using `Visual Studio for Mac`, you should refer to the article below to connect to TFS:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control

First, check the requirements of connecting to Team Foundation version control from VS for Mac, to see whether your environment meets the requirements:

> - Visual Studio Community, Professional, or Enterprise for Mac version
>     7.5 or later.
> - Visual Studio Team Services, or Team Foundation Server 2013 and    later.
> - A Project in Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server,    configured to use Team Foundation Version Control.

Then follow the steps below to install the extension and connect to VSTS/TFS:

1. In Visual Studio for Mac, choose **Visual Studio** > **Extensions**... from the menu. In the **Gallery** tab, select **Version Control** > **Team Foundation Version Control for TFS and VSTS** and click **Install**…:

[image]

2. Updates to the TFVC extension are made periodically. To access updates, choose **Visual Studio** > **Extensions**... from the menu and select the **Updates** tab. Select the extension in the list and press the *Update* button:

[image]

3. Once the extension is installed, select the **Version Control** > **TFS/VSTS** > **Open from Remote Repository** menu item.

Choose either Visual Studio Team Services or Team Foundation Server to get started and press **Continue**:

[image]

4. Enter the TFS server information or VSTS credential, and select a project.

After installing the extension, you can create a workspace from the **Workspace** combobox in the **Open from Source Control** dialog:

[image]

Comment: Update on this answer - this project is no longer being maintained by Microsoft.