# Visual Studio Code changes not reflecting in TFS

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, visual-studio-2017

I have opened Angular application from locally mapped TFS path using VS Code. 
When I make some changes in application files, changes are not reflecting in TFS. (i.e.., Files are not checked-out.) When I select, check-in pending changes, it shows 'no pending changes'.

Do I need to modify/configure any other settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, make sure you have installed and configured Visual Studio Code and the integration of TFVC properly. Detail steps please refer my answer in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076503/how-can-i-connect-to-on-premises-tfs-using-visual-studio-code/55099310#55099310).

According to your description, please also double check your workspace's configuration if you are using **local workspace** or not.

[image]

A local workspace does automatic detection of changed files. A server workspace requires explicit check out/in to notify the server of pending changes.