# Unable to validate collection

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code

I am trying to set up TFS for vscode. I am getting the error, unable to validate the collection assuming 'default collection', when signing in. Any recommendations oh how to resolve this issue.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Are you using Git or TFVC?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was told we have 2015 but we have 2012.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly make sure you have correctly set the [TFVC support](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md).

Below is a short list of steps to get up-and-running with TFVC support:

- Install the Team Services extension for Visual Studio Code.
- Team Foundation Server requires your domain credentials.
- Ensure you have a TF command line client installed (either TF.exe or
  the TEE CLC).
- Set the tfvc.location VS Code setting to the full path of your TF
  command line client.
- Open a folder containing a **Local TFVC Workspace** and sign in when
  prompted.
- Set the SCM Provider to TFVC.

For more detail tutorial you could also take a look at my reply in this question [How can I connect to on-premises TFS using visual studio code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55076503/how-can-i-connect-to-on-premises-tfs-using-visual-studio-code/55099310#55099310)

Back on the error message, it may related to the workspace.  Check if you have correctly mapped the workspace. Just try to remap the existing workspace or create a new workspace and map sources to a new local folder, then check that again.

Also just try to specify the **collection** and **team project name** in the `user settings` like this:

```
{
    "tfvc.location": "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\Common7\\IDE\\tf.exe",
    "team.remoteUrl": "http://server:8080/tfs/collection",
    "team.teamProject": "TeamProjectName",
    "tfvc.restrictWorkspace": true,
    "window.zoomLevel": 2 
}
```