# how to use tfs source control on an Apple Mac

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code, tfs

Hi I made the mistake of experimenting with an Apple Mac just before the lockdown and now im stuck with it. Now I am trying to work on a tfs project in os as both bootcamp and parallels drivers drain the battery too fast.

As TFS is not supported in visual studio for Mac I have been trying to get it to work in visual studio code. I have installed the extension, but can't get tee clc working (I think its no longer supported)

It appears that tee clc is not compatible with the latest version of oracle.

I have tried installing oracle 10 and folowing this fix [here](https://expicon.se/2017/10/13/tee-clc-not-working-on-mac/#comment-9) but I get an error java.lang.module.FindException: Module java.xml.bind not found

can anybody point me in the right direction. I feel like im missing something as this should not be so hard.

Is TEE clc the right tool to be using. If not how should this be done now?

Thanks

Comment: Hi Paul, any update on this issue. Did you get a chance to implement the solution that I suggested? Were you able to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

We do not have TFS source control, assume you are talking **TFVC** source control. You are right, it is not support with Visual Studio Mac right now. But if you are using Git, it's available in Visual Studio Mac.

More details please take a look at our official doc here-- [Does Visual Studio for Mac support Team Foundation Version Control?](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/mac/tf-version-control?view=vsmac-2019)

> **Unsupported workarounds for TFVC**
>
> While Visual Studio for Mac doesn't officially support TFVC, the rest
>   of this guide provides some workarounds to work with TFVC on macOS. If
>   you're using TFVC for version control today, here are some solutions
>   you can use to access your source code hosted in TFVC:
>
> - Option 1. Use Visual Studio Code and the Azure Repos extension, for a    graphical UI
> - Option 2. Connect to your repo using the Team Explorer Everywhere    Command Line Client (TEE-CLC)

So, Tee clc is the right tool to be using.

> tee-clc (can be installed with HomeBrew), which depends on  Java 6, 7,
>   or 8 (see How to install Java 8 on Mac -- as of this writing, Java 9
>   will not work.)

Make sure you have installed java 8 on your Mac machine. You could also take a look at replies in this question:  [Connect VS code with TFS on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44178141/connect-vs-code-with-tfs-on-mac)  It provide step by step guide of installation and configuration.

Answer (score 0):

You could use https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere CLI tool for TFS support on Mac, or using older JetBrains IDE with TFS plugin,
for example I am using [Rider 2019.3.4](https://www.jetbrains.com/rider/download/other.html) with [TFS plugin](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/4578-tfs)(already obsolete).

Screenshot of JetBrains TFS:
[image]