# How pull and push code in tfvc repo in Azure DevOps Organization?

Tags: visual-studio-code, azure-devops, devops, tfvc, azure-repos

I want to pull and push code from my local ubuntu machine to Azure Repo. I have used repo type tfvc. How can we perform this option from Linux machine?

Comment: Can you please add what you have tried and if you got any error?

Comment: @MoonHorse I  have not found a way to get started on Linux. Could you please tell me how to get started in Linux?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. First Download Team Explorer Everywhere client - https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases
2. Then on Download Azure DevOps Services Plugin for IntelliJ IDEA --https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/azure/devops/java/download-intellij-plug-in?view=azure-devops
3. [Select get from Version Control](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z2Agw.png)
4. Then select your Azure TFVC DevOps Repo and then clone.[select AzureDevops TFVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFQie.png)

Comment: This is great and all, but is the quiestion not about visual studio code????

Answer (score 1):

> How pull and push code in tfvc repo in Azure DevOps Organization?

First we need [install the Visual Studio code on Linux](https://www.sitepoint.com/visual-studio-code-linux/).

Then, we could use the official **[Azure Repos](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vsts.team)** which released by Microsoft.

It supports both **TFVC** and **GIT** version control type.

> **Create your TFVC workspace**
>
> With TFVC, the extension uses information about the current workspace
> to determine how to connect to Team Services (or your Team Foundation
> Server). Workspaces can be created using the Visual Studio IDE,
> Eclipse or with the JetBrains IDEs (e.g, Android Studio, IntelliJ).
>
> *Note: At this time, you will need to have a local TFVC workspace already available on your local machine. More information about the
> difference between the two types (and how to determine which one
> you're using) can be found [here](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#what-is-the-difference-between-a-local-and-server-workspace-how-can-i-tell-which-one-im-working-with).*

You could also take a look at below videos to help get you started using the extension quickly:

- [TFVC Source Code Control for Visual Studio Code](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6IzJ2UPGmoQ&feature=youtu.be) - *This video shows
  you how to set up the TFVC support on Windows and demonstrates much
  of the functionality available for Team Foundation Version Control.*

Above is for windows machine, if you are working on Linux, please take a look at this similar [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006473/5391065).

Hope this helps.