# How to Setup VSTS to work with VS Code over Unix (TEE-CLC)

Tags: tfs, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I had been trying to setup my VS Code and plugin VS Team Services 1.22.0 (need to setup TEE-CLC). But I have been hitting the same wall.

Checks:
-Java Installl
-Download TEE-CLC
-Installed VS Team Services Plug In
-Setup "tfvc.location"
-Created a local folder in my documents

Over TEE-CLC 14.123.1 I had accepted the Eula(Easy process), created a workspace using the TEE in VSTS(with success):
tf workspace -new MyWorkspace -collection:https://dummy.visualstudio.com/
Workspace 'MyWorkspace' created.

Then the part where I get stuck is mapping my local folder.

I had try official setup process(plugging over VS Code)

Used this [How do you create new windows workspace with TFS command line client that is running on unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741880/how-do-you-create-new-windows-workspace-with-tfs-command-line-client-that-is-run/21785438#21785438)

Follow videos to setup TEE-CLC without success.

I know I'm missing something but don't find yet what could be.

Comment: What exactly is not working yet?

Comment: Do you use VSTS or on-premises TFS? If use on-premises TFS, which version of TFS do you use?

Answer (score 0):

If you use on-premises TFS, you must be running Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2 or later.

After installing Team Services extension and TEE CLC (see how to set it up by viewing [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNaEIVZfr0&feature=youtu.be)), you also need the following steps:

1. Set the [tfvc.location](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#configure-tfvc-support) VS Code setting to the full path of your TF command line client.
2. Open a folder containing a Local TFVC Workspace and sign in when prompted. Refer to [this site](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md#open-a-local-tfvc-repository-folder).
3. Set the SCM Provider to TFVC. Refer to [this site](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_13#_install-additional-scm-providers) for more information.

> If you are unable to access the existing local workspace using TEE
>   CLC, try the steps below:
>
> 1. using the CLC, run the `tf workspaces -collection:<collection-url>` command, to help the CLC be aware of the workspaces in the specified
>      collection.
> 2. Run the `tf workfold` command from the local folder being accessed from Visual Studio Code.
>
> Running both commands should make the TEE CLC aware of the workspace
>   and as well as verify that access to it is possible.

I'd like to suggest go through the website below:

https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-vscode/blob/master/TFVC_README.md

Comment: Thanks Cece, Im not using any local TFS server, more trying to connect to Visual Team Services (Online one). I had try to setup the TEE but when I try to complete the steps regarding the workspace over the video is where I got stuck (this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VPNaEIVZfr0&feature=youtu.be) as I try to link it to my Team Service Project but it give an error of access denied.

Comment: Do you have a Personal Access Token (PAT) with All Scopes available? Try to create a new PAT and use this new PAT to see whether you still get access denied error.