# TFVC WSL can't create new local workspace

Tags: unix, azure-devops, windows-subsystem-for-linux, tfvc, team-explorer-everywhere

I use Ubuntu WSL on Windows 10 OS.
In Ubuntu 20.04 LTS I have docker installed for creation docker images.
Then we have on premise Azure Devops Server 2019.
There have source codes in ***git*** and also in ***tfvc***.
With git we have not problems, it's more native with Linux. But with ***tfvc*** I can't create workspace for getting code in next steps.
As described there [How do you create new windows workspace with TFS command line client that is running on unix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21741880/how-do-you-create-new-windows-workspace-with-tfs-command-line-client-that-is-run)
I'm trying to create workspace

```
/home/myuser/TEE-CLC-14.135.0/tf workspace -new SOMECORELIN -collection:http://tfsms.company.local/tfs/DefaultCollection
```

nothing happens.

then I'm trying to view workspace created, like:

```
/home/myuser/TEE-CLC-14.135.0/tf workspaces
```

Result is:

> No local workspaces found.

WSL has access to TFS server.

What is wrong? Maybe there was someone from you who had an experience or a similar problem, please help?

```
java --version
openjdk 11.0.9.1 2020-11-04
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.9.1+1-Ubuntu-0ubuntu1.20.04, mixed mode, sharing)
```

Have a nice day.

Comment: There is an issue on the agent's TEE version before `14.135`(https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases), To resolve that issue, we need update the TEE to `14.135` and copy two files ( `slf4j-api-1.7.19.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.19.jar`) into the lib directory of new TEE from the lib directory of previous Tee (14.134), please try to this to check if it helps you.

Comment: @LeoLiu-MSFT your solution fixes the issue. Many Thanks for your help. I also https://github.com/microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/issues/329 this issue to github and will share your answer with microsoft team

Comment: I am glad to know that help you. This is a workaround for that issue, it should be fix in the 14.135 or next version, looking forward to a complete solution. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TFVC WSL can't create new local workspace

There is an issue about the TEE version before 14.135 on that agent:

[Linux+TFVC checkout failures after Azure DevOps 2020 RC1 upgrade](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-agent/issues/3059)

To resolve that issue, we need update the TEE to `14.135` and copy two files ( `slf4j-api-1.7.19.jar` and `slf4j-log4j12-1.7.19.jar`) into the lib directory of new TEE from the lib directory of previous Tee (14.134).

Comment: Issue is still present at the time of writing this, and the fix still works.